# Pylint invalid constant name

Tags: python, coding-style, pylint

I'm receiving a Pylint error regarding my constant: `MIN_SOIL_PARTICLE_DENS` (invalid name).
Any ideas why this constant is wrong? Here's my full function:

```
def bulk_density(clay, sand, organic_matter):
    MIN_SOIL_PARTICLE_DENS = 2.65
    x1 = (0.078 + 0.278 * sand + 0.034 * clay + 0.022 * organic_matter - 0.018
          * sand * organic_matter - 0.027 * clay * organic_matter - 0.584 * sand
          * clay)
    x2 = -0.107 + 1.636 * x1
    field_capacity = vol_water_content_33_j_kg(clay, sand, organic_matter)#m3/m3
    sat_water_content = 0.043 + field_capacity + x2 - 0.097 * sand
    return (1 - sat_water_content) * MIN_SOIL_PARTICLE_DENS
```

Comment: Unfortunately Pylint tries to change the meaning of the word "constant" and it does not follow PEP 8. --- I think that the wording of the "C0103 Constant name" message should be fixed (e.g. changed to suspected constant) and the check should be disabled by default. --- See also [PyLint wants a variable to be named as a constant C0103](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70642815/320437)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

When checking names, Pylint differentiates between constants, variables, classes etc. Any name that is not inside a function/class will be considered a constant, anything else is a variable.

See http://docs.pylint.org/features.html#basic-checker

> variable-rgx:
>   `[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$`
>
> const-rgx:
>   `(([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)|(__.*__))$`

Because you're in a function, `MIN_SOIL_PARTICLE_DENS` is (according to pylint) supposed to be a variable, pylint however treats it as a constant and therefore complains.

This means you can't have any uppercase names inside functions without pylint complaining.

---

If you ask me, using uppercase inside functions is fine; not all constants are necessarily defined globally.

Comment: If it's constant, why do you want to reassign its value for each call to this method? It could be defined outside this method.

Comment: @Maxime my idea is to have the method independent (not needing outside constants), even though it may take a performance tow because of reassignment of constants. Good point though.

Comment: @user2457899 Actually, I also use constants in my methods. I was just trying to express the idea behind this pylint rule. :)

Comment: I don't know, I think I'd rather have constants outside of functions. If it wasn't really a global constant, it should be a variable.

Comment: @MaximeChéramy Can you express the idea behind why `func_name = make_func(1,2,3)` could be considered wrong? Current use case is `vlen = numpy.vectorize(len)` in utils module to work with ragged arrays in [h5py](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/special.html#arbitrary-vlen-data).

Answer (score 1):

Few simple rules :

1. Constants should be defined with `UPPER_CASE` letters only and should be defined at the module level
2. Class names should be defined with `CamelCase` letters
3. Variables should be defined at `lower_case` and should be defined inside function, classes etc.

Now lets talk about your case,

`MIN_SOIL_PARTICLE_DENS` is defined inside a function and should have lower letters only. Thus instead of considering `MIN_SOIL_PARTICLE_DENS` as a constant, pylint considers it as a variable here and hence the pylint error.

[Pylint Tutorial](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)

Comment: What are these rules? In Python we have constants which are not at the module level and we have variables which are at module level. --- Because of the wrong assumptions in the "rules" Pylint shows wrong messages and encourages users to not follow PEP 8.

Answer (score 1):

I found this behavior annoying, but there's a way to configure pylint to avoid this!

Merge the following ini-style declaration into your `.pylintrc` file:

```
[BASIC]
variable-rgx=((([a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,})|(_[a-z0-9_]*)|(__[a-z][a-z0-9_]+__))$)|([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]+$)
```

I built this regex by taking

- the default snake_case regex taken from [pylint's source at this line](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/fde732e0e9a4f224c5ae48ad942c6d955aa0a8e6/pylint/checkers/base.py#L95),
- the default CONST_VAR regex taken from [pylint's source at this line](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/fde732e0e9a4f224c5ae48ad942c6d955aa0a8e6/pylint/checkers/base.py#L128)

and joining them by `|` and some parentheses.

Theoretically, you could also just take `.*`, but this would allow even invalid names like `mixed_CASE`.