# Getting invalid function name warning using Python

Tags: python, pylint

I am formatting Python code using `pylint` and getting some unwanted warning messages which are given below.

```
C:204, 0: Invalid function name "sendPasswordViaEmail" (invalid-name)
C:207, 4: Invalid variable name "to" (invalid-name)
W:213, 4: Statement seems to have no effect (pointless-statement)
```

I am providing my code related to the above messages below.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('uname')
        email = request.POST.get('uemail')
        range_start = 10 ** (4 - 1)
        range_end = (10 ** 4) - 1
        password = randint(range_start, range_end)
        passw = User(
            uname=name,
            password=password,
            raw_password=password,
        )
        passw.save()
        sendPasswordViaEmail(str(password), email)
    return render(request, 'bookingservice/login.html')


def sendPasswordViaEmail(password, email):
    """ Send email to user"""

    to = email
    gmail_user = settings.EMAIL
    gmail_pwd = settings.PASSWORD
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    smtpserver.ehlo
    smtpserver.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
    header = 'To:' + to + '\n' + 'From: ' + \
        gmail_user + '\n' + 'Subject:password \n'
    msg = header + '\n Your password is\n\n' + password
    smtpserver.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg)
    smtpserver.close()
```

Comment: That's a [PyLint](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:c0103) message. "*Used when a name doesn't doesn't fit the naming convention associated to its type (constant, variable, class…)*".

Comment: Check this up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25184336/2955375

Comment: sendPasswordViaEmail is an invalid name. Right name is send_password_via_email

Answer (score 11):

These messages are warnings (your code works), not errors.

`sendPasswordViaEmail` is a camel case name. Functions should be "snake case". Rename it `send_password_via_email`.

`to` is too short. Try `recipient` or something else meaningful in place.

The line containing `smtpserver.ehlo` whithout parentheses does nothing and is thus useless.

Comment: That last one is weird. Does `pylint` really check that you aren't accessing a descriptor with side effects?