# PyLint wants a variable to be named as a constant [C0103]

Tags: python, pylint

Why does PyLint require a variable to have UPPER_CASE naming as though it is a constant?

```
"""Stack reproducible example."""

some_list = ['foo', 'bar']
for i in some_list:
    counter = 3
    while counter != 0:
        print("Value of 'counter': " + str(counter))
        counter -= 1
```

This gives the linting error of:

```
# C0103: Constant name "counter" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming style (invalid-name)
```

However unlike Avogadro's Constant, Pi, or the speed of sound in a vaccum, the value of  `counter` changes which surely must render it a 'variable'?

I have read the page regarding [C0103](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:c0103) but I obviously don't understand something.

Is a for-loop considered a single-use function thus altering convention such as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184097/pylint-invalid-constant-name)?

Comment: Unfortunately Pylint tries to change the meaning of the word "constant" and it does not follow PEP 8. --- I think that the wording of the "C0103 Constant name" message should be fixed (e.g. changed to suspected constant) and the check should be disabled by default. --- See also [Why does pylint require capitalized variable names when outside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54151197/320437) and [Pylint invalid constant name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25184097/320437)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See 2 solutions [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2166):

> 1. This is not a false positive. Pylint expects all variables at the module level to be upper case. This behaviour can be configured by
>    passing an updated const-rgx setting in the configuration file.
> 2. Just want to add that another solution is to add logger to good-names setting in the configuration file.

Comment: This is useful, but why does the official documentation show module nomenclature as `(([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+))$`? Is it incorrect, or do I not understand it correctly?

Comment: See in the link - there is a big conversation on it..

Comment: Variables at the module level have a large scope. It seems wise to me to highlight this with CAPS. My solution would be to put the code snippet in a function.