# How can I make a variable a constant in python for pylint?

Tags: python, pylint

I'm trying to solve most of the issues I find with pylint, but I'm having troubles with this one:

> C0103: Variable name "ELEMENT_CLASS" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style (invalid-name)

This is an example of the piece of code:

```py
def get_title(driver: Chrome) -> str:
    """
    Extract title of the location section
    """
    ELEMENT_CLASS = 'content-intro'
    try:
        element: WebElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (
                    By.XPATH,
                    f'//div[contains(@class,"{ELEMENT_CLASS}")]')
                )
            )
    except TimeoutException:
        print(f'{ELEMENT_CLASS} could not be found')
        raise

    return element.text
```

I want to make visible that my class is hard coded and is a constant. I though the convention for that was having it as upper case (as for example in vscode it is highlighted in a different color).

What can I do to solve this issue (as pylint would like)?

NOTE: I do not want to add a new rule in the `pylintrc` or just `type: ignore` it. I want to know what is the "right way" or most common way of writing this kind of constants.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184097/pylint-invalid-constant-name

Comment: Have you tried `element_class = ...`? One usually defines true constants *globally*, so (I suspect) PyLint treats any local variable as, well, a *variable*.

Comment: @chepner, yes, that would remove the pylint error, but I would say that is less obvious to read. I would assume that if it is lower case it will change at some point in the function. For example `ELEMENTS = {'a': 'class_1'}` and then variable  `element_class = ELEMENTS['a']`

Comment: Hence my point that constants are usually declared *globally*. Don't redefine `ELEMENT_CLASS` every time you call `get_title`; define it *once* at the global scope and let `get_title` use that global when you call it. (Global variables are not the problem; *mutable* global variables are. There is no problem using global constants in a function. Your function is already full of global variables that don't change: `WebElement`, `WebDriverWait`, `EC`, `By`, and `TimeoutException` are *all* names defined globally.)

Comment: I think I understand the reasoning now that you mention it. Still I think, if you have a module with many functions like the ones in the example, moving the constants up to be globally available, would make the code harder to read because you have to keep jumping in the code to something that only affects that function and may not be reusable.